# Why the queue still joining after I called task_done()?

Tags: python, multithreading

Python3.6

First I put some items in a queue, then start a thread and called join() of the queue in the main thread, then called get() in the thread loop, when the size of queue == 0, I called task_done() and break loop and exit from the thread. But the join() method still blocked in the main thread. I can not figure out what`s wrong.

Below is the code

Thanks

```
import queue
import threading

def worker(work_queue):
    while True:
        if work_queue.empty():
            print("Task 1 Over!")
            work_queue.task_done()
            break
        else:
            _ = work_queue.get()
            print(work_queue.qsize())
            # do actual work

def main():
    work_queue = queue.Queue()
    for i in range(10):
        work_queue.put("Item %d" % (i + 1))

    t = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(work_queue, ))
    t.setDaemon(True)
    t.start()
    print("Main Thread 1")
    work_queue.join()
    print("Main Thread 2")
    t.join()
    print("Finish!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`task_done` should be called for each work item which is dequeued and processed, not once the queue is entirely empty. (There'd be no reason for that-- the queue already knows when it's empty.) `join()` will block until `task_done` has been called as many times as `put` was called.

So:

```
def worker(work_queue):
    while True:
        if work_queue.empty():
            print("Task 1 Over!")
            break
        else:
            _ = work_queue.get()
            print(work_queue.qsize())
            # do actual work
```

Note that it's weird for a worker to exit as soon as it sees an empty queue. Normally it would `get()` with blocking, and only exit when it got a "time to exit" work item out of the queue.